# dplyr custom function on each row

Tags: r, dplyr

I start to use `dplyr` and I want to cast my old `plyr` program in `dplyr`
I have a dataframe with this columns :

```
model,label, value0,value1,value2..... , value100
```

I want to use `dplyr` in order to add a new column `rms` which run call a value0 to value 100 as input argument of this function `rms`

```
rms <- function(value){
    rms = sqrt(sum( value^2))/sqrt(length(value))
    return (rms)
}
```

How can I call my input argument within mutate.

```
table %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(rms= rms( ???)
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to convert the data into long format first using `gather` from tidyr.  This will allow you to apply your function to a single column.  A simple example

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(model = c("Model1", "Model2", "Model3"),
                 label = c("Label1", "Label2", "Label3"),
                 value0 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 value1 = c(4, 5, 6),
                 value2 = c(7, 8, 9), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

long_df <- df %>%
    gather(value_name, value, -model, -label)

model  label value_name value
1 Model1 Label1     value0     1
2 Model2 Label2     value0     2
3 Model3 Label3     value0     3
4 Model1 Label1     value1     4
5 Model2 Label2     value1     5
6 Model3 Label3     value1     6
7 Model1 Label1     value2     7
8 Model2 Label2     value2     8
9 Model3 Label3     value2     9
```

Now you can apply your function to create an rms value for each group of model and label.

```
rms <- function(value){
  rms = sqrt(sum(value^2))/sqrt(length(value)) 
  return(rms) 
}

rms_df <- long_df %>%
  group_by(model, label) %>%
  summarise(rms = rms(value))
```

You now join `rms_df` back to your original df and bingo, you have an rms column.

```
df <- df %>%
  left_join(rms_df)

   model  label value0 value1 value2      rms 
 1 Model1 Label1      1      4      7 4.690416
 2 Model2 Label2      2      5      8 5.567764
 3 Model3 Label3      3      6      9 6.480741
```

Not using rowwise, maybe someone will come along and explain how to do it that way, but hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice. 
Honnestly, i thought about this solution but through the Reshape pakage.

I am sure there is a solution with dplyr
if i do :

```
table %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(rms= rms( c(Frame0,Frame2))
```

i can run my function on frame0 and Frame 2. But that fails if i use c("Frame0","frame2")

I would like a full dplyr solution. 
cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure what Frame0 and Frame2 are, but here's a slightly altered method that gets around the joining thing.  Again using my made up df.

```
df <- data.frame(model = c("Model1", "Model2", "Model3"),
                 label = c("Label1", "Label2", "Label3"),
                 value0 = c(1, 2, 3),
                 value1 = c(4, 5, 6),
                 value2 = c(7, 8, 9), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

We use `tidyr::gather` to convert the df into long format, then apply your function to single column and then use `tidyr::spread` to convert it back to wide format.  Tidyr and dplyr are intended to work together, so I don't think you gain much from a "full dplyr solution".

```
rms_df <- df %>%
  gather(value_name, value, -model, -label) %>%
  group_by(model, label) %>%
  mutate(rms = rms(value)) %>%
  spread(value_name, value)

> rms_df
Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
   model  label      rms value0 value1 value2
  (chr)  (chr)    (dbl)  (dbl)  (dbl)  (dbl)
1 Model1 Label1 4.690416      1      4      7
2 Model2 Label2 5.567764      2      5      8
3 Model3 Label3 6.480741      3      6      9
```